# Google Maps infowindow outside map on marker click event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails

I would like to dedicate ~2/3 of the page width to a Google Map, and ~1/3 to a div that displays information content of an `infowindow` for the clicked-on marker.

Upon a click on a certain marker, that marker would be highlighted to indicate the marker that the displayed information relates to.

Reason: I have a lot of markers in a close proximity and triggering an `infowindow`

Question: How could I display information of an `infowindow` for each marker in that div element, instead of overlaying an `infowindow` over the map?

UPDATE:
I am using `gmaps4rails`, and create a bunch of markers using the `addMarkers` method with the following argument (an array of markers with its own latitude, longitude, etc):

`{'lat' => img["coords"]["latitude"].to_s,
lng' => img["coords"]["longitude"].to_s,
'infowindow' => img["imagePath"]+"<br/><a target='_blank' href='../get_image?path=" + img['imagePath']+"'><img style='height: 400px' src='../get_image?path=" + file_path+"'/></a>"}`

I get a map with markers that have individual infoboxes (image path + an image).

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Simply set the innerHTML of the div to the desired content. It's not clear where the informations(content) come from.

Comment: yet another update to my question :)

Comment: oh, so basically, listen to the `click` event on a marker, and run a function that updates the `div` element? or? :)

Comment: correct, that's what I meant(you may store the infowindow-property of the passed argument as a property of the marker and when the marker has been clicked set the innerHTML of the div to this marker-property)